# Backbone view not getting the JSON objects

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, backbone.js, model-view-controller

Making a Rails app with Backbone on the frontend. There are two Backbone models, Publications and Articles. I am having issues rendering one of my Backbone views. Here is the code that is giving me an issue:

```
SimpleGoogleReader.Views.PublicationsIndex = Backbone.View.extend({

  template: JST['publications/index'],

  el: '#publication',

  events:{
    'click #new_feed': 'createFeed'
  },

  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.model, "sync", this.render);
  },

  render: function(){
    this.$el.html( this.template({publications: this.model.toJSON()}) );
    return this;
  },

  createFeed: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var feed_url = $('#new_feed_name').val();
    // var that = this;

    this.model.create(
      {url: feed_url},
      { success: function(data){
          $.post('/articles/force_update', {url: feed_url, publication_id: data.id}, function(data){
          });
        }
      }
    );

  }

});
```

I know the render function is getting called and when I console.log(this.model.toJSON()) it does not return the JSON objects. However the render function works just fine within the Articles View:

```
SimpleGoogleReader.Views.ArticlesIndex = Backbone.View.extend({

  template: JST['articles/index'],

  el: '#article',

  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.model, "sync", this.render);
  },

  render: function(){
    console.log(this.model.toJSON());
    this.$el.html( this.template({articles: this.model.toJSON()}) );
    return this;
  }

});
```

** Edit ** here is my router where I instantiate the views:

```
SimpleGoogleReader.Routers.Publications = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    '': 'home',
    'all_articles': 'get_all_articles',
    'publications/:id': 'articles_by_id',
    'publications/:id/delete': 'delete_publication'
  },

  home: function(){

    var publications = new SimpleGoogleReader.Collections.Publications();
    var articles = new SimpleGoogleReader.Collections.Articles();
    var pubIndex = new SimpleGoogleReader.Views.PublicationsIndex({model: publications});
    var artIndex = new SimpleGoogleReader.Views.ArticlesIndex({model: articles});

    articles.listenTo(publications, "sync", function(){
      articles.fetch( {success: function(){}} );
    });

    publications.fetch();

  },
```

Any ideas on where the discrepancy may lie?

Comment: How are you instantiating these views?

Comment: See edit. Hope thats what you meant

Comment: Ok, but why does it work for the one view but not the other?

Comment: Also, if I just console.log(this.model) I get:                      child {length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object, _listenId: "l2", _events: Object…}

Comment: There should be at least one Publication in there

Comment: I think we would need to see as well the code of your Publications and Articles.

Comment: The code for the views is posted. What are you referring to?

Comment: The collections that should be models or the other way around...

Comment: The models are very basic, they just define the urlRoot. Similarly the collections are also very basic, they just define the url and the model.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49190/discussion-between-puigcerber-and-user2623706)